# squeezing spaces that aren't in quotes in bash

Tags: regex, bash, quotes

I'm trying to figure out a way to squeeze spaces that are not in quotes (both double and single) in bash.  I would use `tr -s` but it won't cut it. I would like to have the following line in a text file (foo.txt):

```
    "      not  squeezed      "     squeeze     this     part
```

turn into:

```
    "      not  squeezed      " squeeze this part
```

Of course it gets more complicated with nested single, double, escaped quotes so I wondering if there was some kind of command already written for this?

EDIT:

if I tried:

```
    cat foo.txt | tr -s
```

I would get the output:

```
    " not squeezed " squeeze this part
```

which squeezes the spaces inside the quotes - which is undesirable

Comment: What is this for?  Is `foo` a command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is context sensitive, so you have to parse it yourself.

e.g.

```
cat foo.txt | (
st=0; lc=""; od -v -t o1  | cut -b 9- |
while read line
 do
  for t in $line
   do
    if [[ $st == 1 ]] ; then
     printf \\$t
    else
     if [[ "$t" != "040" ]] ; then
      printf \\$t
     else
      if [[ "$lc" != "040" ]] ; then
       printf \\$t
      fi
     fi
    fi
    if [[ "$t" == "042" ]] ; then
     st=$((1-$st))
    fi
    lc="$t"
   done
 done)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It's called `echo` ... if you don't need the double quotes to be printed. If you do, first escape all unescaped `"` and all `\` with `\`.

If this is not an option, you have to just cough up a small bash script that basically prints all its arguments, surrounded by `"` depending on previous arguments.

Comment: I like this approach. I use echo all the time to squeeze stuff. It seems like the correct way to go, but I can't picture the actual code that solves this problem. Mind taking the time to write it up?